# aspnetdb is not getting populated with roles?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I have maintained aspnetdb.mdf on a sqlserver instance which I am using in my ASP.net web site application for roles and memberships.
Problem is that when I add roles using ASP.net web site configuration tool these roles are not getting populated in my **aspnet_Roles table** in aspnetdb.

On the other hand Users and application settings are nicely getting inserted into tables aspnet_Users and aspnet_Applications table respectively?
I know there is something wrong in my web.config file but do not know what?

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlSequrityConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=NASEER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="56013" />
    </authorization>

    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />

    <membership defaultProvider="SecurityTutorialsSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <!-- Add a customized SqlMembershipProvider -->
        <clear/>
        <add name="SecurityTutorialsSqlMembershipProvider"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName="SqlSequrityConnectionString"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        applicationName="SecurityTutorials"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Hashed"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Looks OK from here. What does your C# code look like?

Comment: For now I am using built in ASP.net web site administration tool to add roles.Only roles are not getting inserted otherwise users and applications are nicely getting inserted in respective tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding following code I got it working........!

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">
      <providers>
        <add name="SqlRoleManager"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
             connectionStringName="SqlSequrityConnectionString"
             applicationName="MyApplication" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```